# How to run TackleTest using Docker image on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker, software-design, software-distribution, windows-10-desktop

We are running on Windows 10. Instructions said to mount a working
directory to a docker container. We have everything and still can't
get Tackle Test to run tests on applications. What are we missing?